# Converting binary TRMM to GeoTIFF using R?

Tags: r, convert, geotiff-tiff, binary, trmm

I´m trying to convert a binary image of TRMM satellite to Geotiff format using this R code:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Hugo/Desktop")
trmm.data.file<-"C:/Users/Hugo/Desktop/3B42_daily.2013.04.22.7.bin"
trmm.data<-readBin("3B42_daily.2013.04.22.7.bin", "numeric", size=4, signed = TRUE, n = 1440 * 400, endian = "little")
trmm.array <- array(trmm.data, dim = c(400, 1440))
trmm.raster <- raster(trmm.array, xmn = -180, xmx = 180, ymn = -50, ymx= 50, crs = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84')
trmm.crop<-crop(trmm.raster, e)  # 'e' is the box of my region of interest
plot(trmm.crop)
setwd("C:/Users/Hugo/Desktop/")
writeRaster(trmm.crop,filename="trmmcrop.tiff",format="GTiff",overwrite=TRUE)
```

But it seems not to work, the pixel values are incoherent and the resolution is wrong.

Any idea about how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I once wrote some functions to automate data download and processing of TRMM 3B42 binary data. [`downloadTRMM`](https://github.com/environmentalinformatics-marburg/Rsenal/blob/master/R/downloadTRMM.R) and [`rasterizeTRMM`](https://github.com/environmentalinformatics-marburg/Rsenal/blob/master/R/rasterizeTRMM.R) are included in our working group's [**Rsenal** package](https://github.com/environmentalinformatics-marburg/Rsenal). You can either install it via **devtools**

```
devtools::install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg/Rsenal")
library(Rsenal)
```

or, if installation fails (after all, it's a package in the making), download and install the latest version manually from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7gk4wy5uj7mpgm/Rsenal_0.2.7.tar.gz?dl=0). After that, the rasterization is quite straight-forward.

```
## download TRMM 3B42 data from Jan 1 to Jan 4, 2015
fls_trmm <- downloadTRMM(begin = "2015-01-01", end = "2015-01-04")
fls_trmm

# bin                               xml
# 1 ./3B42_daily.2015.01.02.7.bin ./3B42_daily.2015.01.02.7.bin.xml
# 2 ./3B42_daily.2015.01.03.7.bin ./3B42_daily.2015.01.03.7.bin.xml
# 3 ./3B42_daily.2015.01.04.7.bin ./3B42_daily.2015.01.04.7.bin.xml
# 4 ./3B42_daily.2015.01.05.7.bin ./3B42_daily.2015.01.05.7.bin.xml

## rasterize downloaded data
lst_trmm <- lapply(1:nrow(fls_trmm), function(i) {
  rasterizeTRMM(binary = fls_trmm[i, 1], meta = fls_trmm[i, 2], 
                write_out = FALSE)
})
rst_trmm <- raster::stack(lst_trmm)
```

[image: trmm_global]

Feel free to browse the source code and tell me if anything goes wrong.

Comment: The rasterizeTRMM function is very convenient. There were some quirks in the download code so, I rewrote it and removed the "lubridate" dependency, just using the POSIXlt class. It does look like they have a 10 file download limit before the ftp locks you out. Any idea on the authentication credentials for the ftp?

Comment: Hm, in a different context (MODIS evapotranspiration data), I found such lock-downs were caused by `RCurl::getURL` and could be circumvented by including something like `Sys.sleep(300)`. I'll have a look at it!

Comment: Thank you very much!

I could not install the package. I´m trying to use the functions isolated. But appears this error when I try to download the TRMM data:

"Error in download.file(j, tmp_ch_fls_out) : 
  cannot open destfile './3B42_daily.2014.01.02.7.bin.xml
', reason 'Invalid argument'"

Comment: @JeffreyEvans I decided to manually create on-line filepaths in order to avoid `RCurl::getURL` and it seems to work with more than 10 files now. I also removed the **lubridate** dependency. @HugoBendini Could you please test the new function version which is now on [GitHub](https://github.com/environmentalinformatics-marburg/Rsenal/blob/master/R/downloadTRMM.R) and tell me if everything works as expected?

Comment: By the way, what is the difference between the "rasterizeTRMM" and Daniel´s script posted below?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I also used Robert's initial code snippet from r-sig-geo as basis for my approach, so there is not much difference. Mine is a function and it creates the raster template dynamically via the metadata file (`.xml`) rather than statically (i.e., hard-coded bounding box and dimensions) - I guess that's the only true difference.

Answer (score 1):

I was not aware of the Rsenal package. It looks very nice and easy. Will have to take a look. What I did here was Robert Hijmans code from r-sig-geo [1](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.geo/12285/match=trmm)

```
require(raster)
# trmm template
trmm <- raster(xmn=-180, xmx=+180, ymn=-50, ymx=50, ncol=1440, nrow=400)
filename <- "3B43.980101.7.precipitation.accum"
trmm[] <- readBin(filename, 'double', n=576000, size=4, endian='big')
# normalize (North up, -180.. 180)
x <- flip(trmm, 'y')
# write to geotif
x <- writeRaster(x, extension(filename, 'tif'))
plot(x)
```

You could put that into a loop and process all in batch